# C++ database communication library

Tags: c++, database-connection

I'm looking for a well designed, efficient and robust C++ cross-database and cross-platform database communication library.
I need support for

- Oracle
- MySQL
- PostgreSQL
- Firebird (optional)
- MSSQL (optional)

When I say cross-platform I really mean cross-platform, I need something similar to boost.

Currently I'm researching [soci](http://soci.sourceforge.net/), but

- I'm not sure how portable and good this library is
- I would like to have an alternatives.

Currently I'm using Qt, but I don't like using Qt only for database communication, while no other Qt features used. It's a temporary solution and I'm looking for a replacement.

What libraries do you use? What can you recommend? If you know any really good and portable Oracle communication library that's also acceptable, but cross-database is preferred.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using: Progress [DataDirect Connect® and Connect XE](http://www.datadirect.com/products/odbc/matrix/connectodbc.htm)

Intresting options:

- http://www.sqlapi.com/
- http://www.thefreecountry.com/sourcecode/database.shtml
- http://www.trumphurst.com/cpplibs/cpplibs.php

Comment: http://www.sqlapi.com/ - not enough cross-platform. It supports only gcc, visual studio and borland c++ and not even free.

Comment: DataDirect Connect® and Connect XE - looks like it uses ODBC. I forgot to say that it's better to have native connection to the database, but if there will be no other choice that is acceptable.

Comment: Actually I'm not asking to search something for me, I'm asking to share your experience with specific libraries. I don't want to download (or buy) some library, which in fact doesn't work as it should and therefore spend time.

Comment: I have been using Progress DataDirect. It has a  has a big user base, such as Tibco and IBMs C++ based products. ODBC is OK nowadays, but native libraries are better.  if you are using C++ inhouse the licence/price is not that bad, but if you are distributing open source componenents it is horrible...

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Database Template Library](http://dtemplatelib.sourceforge.net/) to good effect with Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/) (Oracle Template Library). Despite the name, it has backends for different databases and works in different platforms. It also very simple to use. Just add the header.

I also tried Soci, nothing wrong with that but I decided to go with OTL. It was simply easier to include it to my project.